# Missing } Inserted numcases environment

Tags: amsmath, cases

I am trying to make a simple list of numbered cases for a particular equation using the numcases environment using the code below. However, whenever the code is run it throws a "Missing } inserted" error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{numcases}{S_{k}=}
    $1 - \frac{I_{k}}{\psi_{k}}$ for $I_{k} < \psi_{k}$, \\
    0 for $I_{k} \geq \psi_{k}$.
\end{numcases}
\end{document}
```

Taking the equations out of the numcases environment like so:

```
$1 - \frac{I_{k}}{\psi_{k}}$ for $I_{k} < \psi_{k}$
0 for $I_{k} \geq \psi_{k}$
```

does not produce any errors when typesetting them on their own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The body of `numcases` is already in math mode, and the second part is alread in `\text{}`. So you are basically switching it off with the first `$`. I would use the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{numcases}{S_{k}=}
    1 - \frac{I_{k}}{\psi_{k}} & for $I_{k} < \psi_{k}$, \\
    0                          & for $I_{k} \geq \psi_{k}$.
\end{numcases}
\end{document}
```

[image]