How to number 2 equations separately inside a curly bracket
Please tell me how to number 2 equations separately inside a curly bracket. I tried begin_align + begin_cases + label_1 + label_2 + end_cases + end_align, but the system gives 1 number for 2 equations. I tried begin_align + \left{ + begin_aligned + label_1 + label_2 + end_aligned + \right. + end_align, but the result remained the same.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Try to use numcases of cases package. An example of it use you can find in @Rmano answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507628/missing-inserted-numcases-environment

Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464189/nested-cases-alignment-and-numbering
